# pyspark withcolumn insert list in each row

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `df` with one column `type` and I have two lists

```
women = ['0980981', '0987098']
men = ['1234567', '4567854']
```

now I want to add another column based on the value of the `type` column like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as psf
df_ = df.withColumn('new_col', psf.when(psf.col('type') == 'men', men).when(psf.col('type') == 'women', women))
```

But I guess we cannot insert list directly as we can insert `Array('1234567', '4567854')` in Scala.
I have tried `psf.lit(men)` as well but no luck.

Any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `pyspark.sql.functions.array`, which takes a `list` of column expressions and returns a single column expression of `Array` type, in conjunction with a `list` comprehension over `men`:

```
men = ['1234567', '4567854']

df = spark.createDataFrame([['women'], ['men']], 'type: string')
df.withColumn('new_col', F.when(F.col('type') == 'men', F.array([F.lit(string) for string in men]))).show()
```

Output:

```
+-----+------------------+
| type|           new_col|
+-----+------------------+
|women|              null|
|  men|[1234567, 4567854]|
+-----+------------------+
```